# French equivalent of the German expression "flöten gehen"

Tags: expressions, allemand

> Damit ist uns wieder die einmalige Chance **flöten gegangen**.
>
> ≈ Et voilà qu'on a encore laissé passer l'occasion rêvée.

The "flöten gehen" -- made up of two verbs: "flöten {play the flute}" and "gehen {go}" -- literally means "(qch/qqn) est allé jouer de la flûte" and figuratively "(qch/qqn) est perdu", only the expression is on the informal/colloquial side, has a rather negative connotation of "going down the drain, going out of the window, being wasted", and can convey a sense of regret for the loss.

> Damit ist mir wieder die hinreißende Frau **flöten gegangen**.
>
> ≈ Here I am, letting such an attractive woman slip through my fingers again.

How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed in French?

Answer (score 3):

Le verbe [*laisser*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/laisser/1), « permettre de, ne pas empêcher de » (TLFi) est un bon vecteur comme semi-auxiliaire pour d'autres verbes : *(laisser) passer*, *(laisser) s'[envoler](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/envoler)* (l'idée de disparition), entre autres. On peut sans doute aussi penser, toujours avec le verbe *laisser*, à la locution verbale [*partir en fumée*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/partir_en_fum%C3%A9e), « disparaître sans espoir de retour » (Wiktionnaire). On peut sans doute aussi faire un constat d'abandon relatif à l'occasion avec la locution [*tomber à l'eau*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tomber_%C3%A0_l%E2%80%99eau), « n’être plus envisagé, être abandonné, être annulé » (Wiktionnaire).

> Encore une occasion rêvée qu'on a laissé passer/s'envoler/partir en
>   fumée. 
>  Encore une occasion rêvée qui est tombée à l'eau.

---

L'approximation avec [*slip through your fingers*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/slip-through-your-fingers) rappelle une idée similaire avec le verbe (laisser) [*filer*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/filer), probablement le *déplacement rapide* ou *s'en aller*. Selon moi ce serait sans doute une extension de sens de dire exactement (laisser) [*filer entre les doigts*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/filer/33698/locution?q=filer#172097), dans le sens d'« échapper à quelqu'un sans qu'il puisse le retenir » ou ça signifierait autre chose comme ne pas pouvoir [*retenir ou dilapider*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/filer_entre_les_doigts) une relation en cours (« Cet amour m'a filé entre les doigts » dit Wiktionnaire). De plus c'est au figuré ou par métonymie qu'on laisse s'échapper quelqu'un ici :

> Me voici encore qui laisse filer l'occasion de me retrouver avec un(e)
>   femme/homme aussi séduisant(e).
>  Une autre occasion de me
>   retrouver avec une personne aussi séduisante qui me file entre les
>   doigts.

Comment: Je trouve fascinante cette tournure pour le moins inattendue de *«un(e) femme/homme séduisant(e)»*.

Comment: Je comprend et salue cette volonté de généralisation complète. J’ai été surpris cependant de la mention de *femme* avant *homme*, attendu que la version masculine de l’article et de l’adjectif est lue avant la féminine...

Comment: @Montéedelait C'est bien vrai, je n'avais pas remarqué. J'avais sans doute construit la phrase avec homme/femme en tête puis j'ai inversé volontairement l'ordre comme je le fais parfois, et il m'aurait fallu écrire _une/un_ et j'aurais sans doute pu laisser l'adjectif tel quel. Si c'était pour un débutant et que la question portait sur l'apprentissage du genre je pense que je le modifierais sans doute mais dans ce cas-ci ça m'importe moins... on peut le corriger si on veut...

Answer (score 1):

*Rater/manquer le coche* can also be an equivalent idiom, with a very frequent colloquial variant *louper le coche* (a *coche* being a horse-drawn coach or a specific kind of boat, but the word is no longer used nowadays except in this phrase). It means "to miss a very good, unique opportunity".

> En négligeant le marché de la photo numérique, Kodak a loupé le coche.

Answer (score 1):

An expression with a very similar meaning and feel is “être parti aux oubliettes”, which in your context can be used as follows:

> Et voilà (pour nous) l'occasion rêvée partie (encore une fois) aux oubliettes.

“Tomber aux oubliettes” is maybe more standard, but it verges on the side of “to be forgotten” or “to have become obsolete”, whereas “partir aux oubiettes” is sometimes used colloquially for “having been lost” or “wasted”.